# Is there any way to make coroutine channel follow a specific order rather than first-in first-out during receiving

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have some tasks which along with three step to execute, the first&third steps must run in sequentially, only the second step run in concurrently, giving the kotlin **Channel** followed first-in first-out order, I can't always make the step3 run in sequentially, does any imlementation can fit my purpose, or another data structure?

below is my demonstrate code:

```kotlin
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.random.Random

class SortingReceiveChannelTest(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) {
    private val tasks = List(30) { Task(it) }

    private val randomDelay = Random(Int.MAX_VALUE)
    private val step2Channel = Channel<Task>(2)
    private val step3Channel = Channel<Task>()

    fun start() {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            for (task in tasks) {
                task.step1()
                step2Channel.send(task)
            }
        }

        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repeat(tasks.size) {
                val task = step2Channel.receive()
                coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    task.step2()
                    step3Channel.send(task)
                }
            }
        }

        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repeat(tasks.size) {
                val task = step3Channel.receive()
                task.step3()
            }
        }
    }

    inner class Task(val index: Int) {
        fun step1() {
            Log.i(TAG, "execute step1[$index] sequential")
            // sleep to simulating a long run task
            Thread.sleep(randomDelay.nextLong(100, 200))
//            Log.i(TAG, "step1[$index] executed")
        }

        fun step2() {
            Log.i(TAG, "execute step2[$index] concurrently")
            if (index == 2 || index == 5 || index == 8 || index == 16) {
                // make specific tasks run longer to mess the step3's order
                Thread.sleep(randomDelay.nextLong(2000, 5000))
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(randomDelay.nextLong(100, 300))
            }
//            Log.i(TAG, "step2[$index] executed")
        }

        fun step3() {
            Log.i(TAG, "execute step3[$index] sequential")
            Thread.sleep(randomDelay.nextLong(100, 300))
//            Log.i(TAG, "step3[$index] executed")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SortChannel"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- Steps 1, 2, and 3 must happen sequentially
- Steps 1 and 3 must be processed sequentially for each of the items of the task list in the same order they were in the source list.

One way to do this is to eliminate the intermediary Channel and instead sending both the secondary job and the task together to the final Channel:

```
class SortingReceiveChannelTest(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) {
    private val tasks = List(30) { Task(it) }

    private val randomDelay = Random(Int.MAX_VALUE)
    private val step3Channel = Channel<Pair<Job, Task>>(capacity = tasks.size)

    fun start() {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            for (task in tasks) {
                task.step1()
                val step2Job = coroutineScope.launch { task.step2() }
                step3Channel.send(step2Job to task)
            }
        }

        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repeat(tasks.size) {
                val (step2Job, task) = step3Channel.receive()
                step2Job.join()
                task.step3()
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Please note the last example doesn't process step1 and step3 concurrently to each other. Sending tasks/jobs through a channel actually makes sense here - to coordinate step1 and step3 which run concurrently.

Comment: @broot, oh, good catch. I'll remove that part.

Comment: One more thing: `Channel()` is by default `RENDEZVOUS`. We need a channel of the size of the number of tasks, because otherwise step3 will inflict a backpressure on step1.

Comment: thank you for reply, the Job.join() work as expected

Answer (score 0):

inspired from Tenfour04's anwser, I tweak a bit, added Semaphore to prevent step1 run too fast as it probably claim many memory to use in product case

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Semaphore

class SortingReceiveChannelTest(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) {
    private val tasks = List(30) { Task(it) }

    private val randomDelay = Random(Int.MAX_VALUE)
    private val step3Channel = Channel<Pair<Job, Task>>(capacity = tasks.size)

    fun start() {
        val semaphore = Semaphore(5)
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            for (task in tasks) {
                semaphore.acquire()
                task.step1()
                step3Channel.send(launch {
                    task.step2()
                    semaphore.release()
                } to task)
            }
        }

        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repeat(tasks.size) {
                val (step2Job, task) = step3Channel.receive()
                step2Job.join()
                task.step3()
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: 1. This is not what OP asked and it is based on a pure guessing about their case. 2. I'm not sure why the memory would be a problem here. 3. Your code solves the problem of fast step1 and slow step2, but it doesn't solve the problem of fast step1 and step2, but slow step3. 4.In the case of fast step1 and step3, but slow step2, your solution may actually decrease the performance. 5. Instead of using a semaphore, we can simply decrease the capacity of the channel. This will also solve the problem of slow step3.

Comment: @broot thanks for your generous reply, for the point 1, I want to make the question understand easilly, so I haven't mention about the memory consideration in the first, in my real scenario, step1 would allocating two bitmaps which maybe large resolution, and do many comparation of their pixels, if run fast will be many bitmaps waiting step2 to process, the step2 collecting all pixels and compress by LZW algorithm, this would take times so I let them run concurrently, then step3 save the data into file, could be fast, I will try decrease capacity for performance, you make me think more, thanks